# u substitution in integrals conceptual question;

Tags: integration

u substitutions are very useful and help us solve many integrals. But in some substitution one does: let $\arccos x= u\rightarrow x=\cos u$. But this is impossible! $x$ can be any number in $\mathbf{R}$ and the range of $\cos u$ is $[-1,1]$, so we can't do this substitution.

I'm asking, is it necessary when doing u substitution to always check the range of the functions?

Comment: $\arccos x$ is not defined (or at the very least not real) except when $x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I know so why they do such substitutions?

Answer (score 0):

$\arccos(x)$ is defined when $x \in [-1, 1]$

If the bounds of the integral are in this domain, then you should be able to make the substitution: $$u = \arccos(x)$$

**EDIT:** When working with special function such as $\arccos(x)$ or $\sqrt{x}$, it's always important to check the domain of the function, because if the bounds of your integral aren't in that domain, then you can't make that substitution. People use substitutions with special functions to simplify integration. For example:

> [Have you heard of Trig Sub?](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TrigSubstitutions.aspx)

Comment: So why some do that substitution?